# Merging MongoDB fields of documents into one document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query

I'm using MongoDB 2.6.6

I have these documents in a MongoDB collection and here is an example:

```
{ ..., "field3" : { "one" : [ ISODate("2014-03-18T05:47:33Z"),ISODate("2014-06-02T20:00:25Z") ] }, ...}
{ ..., "field3" : { "two" : [ ISODate("2014-03-18T05:47:33Z"),ISODate("2014-06-02T20:00:25Z") ] }, ...}
{ ..., "field3" : { "three" : [ ISODate("2014-03-18T05:47:39Z"),ISODate("2014-03-19T20:18:38Z") ] }, ... }
```

I would like the merge these documents in one field. For an example, I would like the new result to be as follows:

```
{ "field3", : { "all" : [ ISODate("2014-03-18T05:47:39Z"),ISODate("2014-03-19T20:18:38Z"),......  ] },}
```

I'm just not sure any more how to have that result!

Comment: It's not really a great example. Do your documents actually have field names that always change such as "one", "two", "three" etc. like you show?

Comment: Yes, these change. I thought it was clear since I named them all differently while field3 was the same in all the documents.

Comment: I ask because it's really not a great practice and it makes the operation considerably more complex than it would need to be were they the same. How would you then know "which" of the fields under "field3" to choose? And moreover what is the purpose of naming like this since there is possibly a better way to do what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I know, but I have a use case in which I need to extract those fields into one for a plot. And I was hoping there was an easy way to do so.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't really leave much to go on here but you can arguably get the kind of merged result with mapReduce:

```js
db.collection.mapReduce(
  function() {
    var field = this.field3;

    Object.keys(field).forEach(function(key) {
      field[key].forEach(function(date) {
        emit( "field3", { "all": [date] } )
      });
    });
  },
  function (key,values) {

    var result  = { "all": [] };

    values.forEach(function(value) {
      value.all.forEach(function(date) {
        result.all.push( date );
      });
    });

    result.all.sort(function(a,b) { return a.valueOf()-b.valueOf() });

    return result;

  },
  { "out": { "inline": 1 } }
)
```

Which being mapReduce is not exactly in the same output format given it's own restrictions for doing things:

```js
{
    "results" : [
            {
                    "_id" : "field3",
                    "value" : {
                            "all" : [
                                    ISODate("2014-03-18T05:47:33Z"),
                                    ISODate("2014-03-18T05:47:33Z"),
                                    ISODate("2014-03-18T05:47:39Z"),
                                    ISODate("2014-03-19T20:18:38Z"),
                                    ISODate("2014-06-02T20:00:25Z"),
                                    ISODate("2014-06-02T20:00:25Z")
                            ]
                    }
            }
    ],
    "timeMillis" : 86,
    "counts" : {
            "input" : 3,
            "emit" : 6,
            "reduce" : 1,
            "output" : 1
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Since the aggregation here into a single document is fairly arbitrary you could pretty much argue that you simply take the same kind of approach in client code.

At any rate this is only going to be useful over a relatively small set of data with next to the same sort of restrictions on the client processing. More than the 16MB BSON limit for MongoDB, but certainly limited by memory to be consumed.

So I presume you would need to add a "query" argument but it's not really clear from your question. Either using mapReduce or your client code, you are basically going to need to follow this sort of process to "mash" the arrays together.

I would personally go with the client code here.

Comment: This indeed gave me the memory size error. Thank you for your answer, but I've resolved into a different method using Logstash filters for merging those fields. I haven't tested your answer on a smaller collection so I'm not sure if I should check it as the correct answer.Thank you!

Comment: @Issy Part of the point in showing you "how" something can be done is often pointing out "why it shouldn't be done that way". Such a response sounds like a definitive answer to me. There really isn't another way to do this aside from external processing as you say you have done, and that also will suffer from similar memory issues of some sort unless you are filtering the content somehow.